# Vlookup to populate values from sheet 1 to sheet 2

Tags: excel, vba

I’m looking for VBA code which would use Vlookup function as following:

1. Look for a column called Hot Data Campaign ID in “Data” sheet and in all it’s cells it will implement the vlookup formula
2. Vlookup formula should consist of:

   a)   For `Lookup_value` it would search for the column called Source Code in the “Data” sheet and take the values located there

   b)   For `Table_array` it will go to “Vlookup” sheet and mark first 4 columns as table array

   c) `Col_index_num = 2`

   d) `Range_lookup = False`

Comment: Try recording a macro that does what you're describing. If you get stuck modifying that, you'll be able to ask specific questions.

Comment: Is there any reason why it has to be in `VBA`? Can't you just put a normal `VLOOKUP` formula in the Hot Data Campaign column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change Sheets("Data").Select to the actual name of the sheet containing your Data

```
Sub VLookupMacro()
    Dim FormulaCol As Long
    Dim LookupCol As Long
    Dim TotalRows As Long
    Dim TotalCols As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Sheets("Data").Select
    TotalRows = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    TotalCols = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

    For i = 1 To TotalCols
        If Cells(1, i).Value = "Hot Data Campaign ID" Then FormulaCol = i
        If Cells(1, i).Value = "Source Code" Then LookupCol = i
    Next

    Cells(2, FormulaCol).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & Cells(2, LookupCol).Address(False, False) & ",Vlookup!A:D,2,FALSE)"
    Cells(2, FormulaCol).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, FormulaCol), Cells(TotalRows, FormulaCol))
    With Range(Cells(2, FormulaCol), Cells(TotalRows, FormulaCol))
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Dear Ripster, Thank you for the code. Something seems to be not 100% right as I got the run-time error ‘1004’ (Application-defined or object-defined error). In the debug mode it highlights this part of the code:

Cells(2, FormulaCol).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & Cells(2, LookupCol).Address(False, False) & ",Vlookup!A:D,2,FALSE"  - do you know what is wrong?

Comment: I forgot a ). The statement should read Cells(2, FormulaCol).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(" & Cells(2, LookupCol).Address(False, False) & ",Vlookup!A:D,2,FALSE)"

Comment: ok it passed through this line and debug system marked the error in the next one (which is the last line): Cells(2, FormulaCol).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, FormulaCol), Cells(TotalRows, TotalCols)) - what should be changed here Ripster?

Comment: Cells(2, FormulaCol).AutoFill Destination:=Range(Cells(2, FormulaCol), Cells(TotalRows, FormulaCol))

Code above has been corrected.

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you Ripster. Is it possible to make those vlookup results in the "hot data campaign ID" column values? You know just like every time using vlookup it is needed to copy the whole column and press insert values only to not loose the data when vlookup array would be deleted

Comment: Brilliant! You were very helpful Ripster. I much appreciate that help.